Accessing small caps digits in Brill font
I'm using Brill font and small caps for running heads (with lualatex and fontspec).  The letters are great, but the numbers don't match them in height. However, in Fontforge I see that there are variants named zero.ST, ..., nine.ST (and *.SP) that match small caps letters (not the default OldStyle ones). How can I access them?
Here is the ME, showing the problem
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Brill-Roman.ttf}[Renderer=Node,Numbers={Lining,Tabular}]

\begin{document}

\scshape test 0123456789

\end{document}


Looks as if fontspec’s Letters=UppercaseSmallCaps option should do the trick, because it’s defined in the c2sc feature.

Thank you, I missed that options somehow

@Thérèse will you turn that into an answer?

@cfr No time for the foreseeable future.  :-(

FontForge reveals that the small cap digits are defined in the c2sc feature (corresponding to the Letters=UppercaseSmallCaps option of fontspec):

FontForge further reveals that Brill's c2sc feature defines small caps which copy and paste as capitals, not minuscules. That’s usually what I want, so I’ve defined a shortcut to use it easily:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Brill}[Numbers={Lining,Tabular}]
\def\smcp#1{{\addfontfeature{Letters=UppercaseSmallCaps}#1}}
\begin{document}
\smcp{TEST test 0123456789} \textsc{TEST test 0123456789}
\end{document}


You could add Letters=SmallCaps to that definition if you want to get small caps whether you type minuscules or capitals.

May I ask why adding ```\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{russian}


@VadimRadionov No idea; I don't use polyglossia. Is babel adequate to your needs, and does it conflict with this solution?

I just don't get small caps for russian letters with babel (in your example)
